# How to calculate distance between two Android app users?

Tags: android, location, server

I'm going to be developing an Android app which requires the knowledge of how far away another active app user is.

- Does a server need to be involved?
- Where is the best place for the calculation to be done?
- If someone is hundreds of miles away, the data shouldn't be fed to the users because it's irrelevant. Where does all this calculation occur if not within the app itself?

From the questions I'm asking I'm getting the idea I need to learn more about server communication and what exactly goes on behind the scenes before information is fed to app users. Still, I'm curious about the location information (the basis of this question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need a server. You need a way to share that information, and that's not going to happen without a server. Now, you could leverage another person's server, like do it through SMS, or email, or whatever, but you still need to get both locations in the same place to do the calculation.

As for where to do the calculation, you can do it wherever you want. It's a simple enough calculation once you have both sets of coordinates.

Should you do it on the server or in the device? Depends. Doing it in your device can give a more fluid experience: you update the information from your contacts, then you calculate with your most recent location. If you do it in the server, you send your location and get the distances from your contacts. The problem with that is that you only get to update the distance when you send your position. On the other hand, if you do it on the server, then you get privacy — you don't need to send the exact position, just the distances. It's a trade-off.